# mvvmcross 5.0 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

After updating mvvmcross to version 5.0.1 application crashes during start with exception

```
No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xc5c3ff70 in tid 9451 (Thread-5)
```

No any stacktrace or error message appeared
What changed on this framework version?

Comment: did you try to remove all bin/obj folders in your solution?

Comment: Yes, no changes

Comment: It would make this a lot easier to diagnose if you included logcat logs of the crash in your post. SIGSEGV errors are pretty general.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no any useful logs(as I wrote at start, no native android stacktrace). Just something like this [mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] /proc/self/maps:
[mono-rt] 12c00000-12e11000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 21754                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)

Comment: I'm talking about [logcat logs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/#Accessing_from_the_Command_Line), not a stack trace or anything in your VS output window.

Comment: It's seems something happened with libmonosgen.so. Logcat contains: Sending message to a Handler on a dead thread. Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel SplashScreen

Comment: Try to clear everything concerning mono/xamarin runtimes on your phone/emulator

Comment: Delete mono runtime and Xamarin android Api-25 support. Application crashed before starting navigation(IMvxAppStart.Start) but after SplashScreen.OnCreate. Logcat shows: Backtrace: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so

Comment: Additional investigate: app crashes on MvxAndroidBindingResource class on private constructor
this.ControlStylableGroupId = (int[])SafeGetFieldValue(styleable, "MvxControl", new int[0]);

It's seems, that app crashes while try GetValue for array properties. I've already disabled linker, but there is the same crash. What can cause this?

Comment: Mvvmcross 5.0.2 fixed this issue